# How many combinations can one make when combining multiple sets in an arbitrary order?

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing a project on passphrase cracking. Correct usage of passphrases is to combine random words, but instead, people often make logical sentences which makes it much weaker. We've noticed that in (for example) a 5-word phrase, 2 words are often very common ("the", "and", etc.; the top 100), 2 words are normal (between top 100 and 15 000), and there is usually 1 word that falls outside the top 15 000 but is within the top 100 000. The question is, how strong is such a passphrase?

To compute the strength, one could list all possible passphrases (given the above constraints), and assume one is picked in a uniformly random manner. Cracking such a phrase takes on average $\frac{possibilities}{2}$ attempts. That's what I'm trying to compute.

If the first two words are easy, the next two words are less common (medium) and the final word is a hard word, then the solution is easy: $len(e)^2*len(m)^2*len(h)$ where $len(category)$ gives the number of words in that category (the length of the given list). But the order is not fixed, the words could be in the order m-e-m-h-e or any other order.

I think the result should be multiplied by $\frac{5!}{2!2!} = 30$, because one can make 30 unique orderings with the five letters of which three unique letters. I've validated the number by using a script that I wrote in the past which lists all possible permutations of the letters within a word. Giving it the word "eemmh" gives 30 results and "eeemmh" gives 60 results (corresponding to $\frac{6!}{3!2!}$).

It shouldn't just be multiplied by $5!$ (120) I think, because swapping the two lists of easy words (or the two medium words) makes no difference and only results in duplicate phrases. Words do not have to be unique: "the taller the boat's mermaid" is a valid phrase but contains 2 identical words. Note that the lists are non-overlapping, so a word from the easy list would not be in the medium list.

The final result would be $len(e)^2*len(m)^2*len(h)*\frac{5!}{2!2!}$ given the above constraints (5 words of which 2 easy words, 2 medium words, one hard word).

Some people disagree and think it should be multiplied by $5!$, or disagree with some other aspect of the calculation. This makes me unsure about my logic, but I don't understand why others think it should be anything else. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order of characters should  matter, than your approach is correct.

> Let's consider the word $\text{MAMA}$. There are precisely  $6$ different valid words built from the characters $\text{M,M,A,A}$, namely
>   \begin{align*}
> AAMM\qquad MAAM\\
> AMAM\qquad MAMA\\
> AMMA\qquad MMAA
> \end{align*}
>   The number is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{4!}{2!2!}}=\frac{24}{2\cdot 2}\color{blue}{=6}
> \end{align*}

We have to divide by $2!$ twice, since an exchange of the two equal characters $A$ and $A$ resp. of the two equal characters $M$ and $M$ can't be distinguished.